# Disable click function on scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey i want to disable the click funktion after scroll but its not working :/

Any solution for this problem? Thanks!

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200)
    {
        $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {anim10();});
    } 
    else
    {     
       $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").off('click')); 
    }
});
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: You are attaching dozens of click event listeners every time you scroll your window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attaching new click event listeners every time you scroll your window, which is why your example is not working.

Instead, try it like this:

```
var $collection = $("#treest").add("#treest2").add("$treest3");
$(window).scroll(function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
       // Removes click event listener
       $collection.off('click')); 
    }
    else {
       // Check if a click event listener is attached, and if not, attaches a new one
       if(!$collection.data('events').click.length) {
           $collection.click(function() {
               anim10();
           });
       }
    }
});
```

In addition, instead of performing dozens of function calls every time you scroll your window and attaching / detaching click event listeners, it's better performance wise to leave the click listener there, and just validate it on every call (as @Milind has suggested in his answer):

```
var $collection = $("#treest").add("#treest2").add("$treest3");
$collection.click(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 200)
        anim10();
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use:

```
 $("#treest, #treest2, #treest3").click(function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() < 200)
 anim10();
 });
```

Comment: no because i have a ajax page and want to disable the click function after 200, thats the Problem

Comment: @user3191542:I dont see any problem implementing above approach there